# XML Document Type with internal DTD

Tags: php, xml

The PHP manual includes an example on how to declare an XML Document Type with an attached DTD:

```
    <?php
    // Creates an instance of the DOMImplementation class
    $imp = new DOMImplementation;

    // Creates a DOMDocumentType instance
    $dtd = $imp->createDocumentType('graph', '', 'graph.dtd');

    // Creates a DOMDocument instance
    $dom = $imp->createDocument("", "", $dtd);

    // Set other properties
    $dom->encoding = 'UTF-8';
    $dom->standalone = false;
    [...]
    ?>
```

Where graph.dtd would look something like

```
    <!ELEMENT graph (id,url)>
    <!ELEMENT id (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT url (#PCDATA)>
```

The result is an XML header like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <!DOCTYPE graph SYSTEM "graph.dtd">
```

How can I use `DOMImplementation->createDocumentType` to create an internal (vs. attached) DTD to get something like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <!DOCTYPE graph [
      <!ELEMENT graph (id,url)>
      <!ELEMENT id (#PCDATA)>
      <!ELEMENT url (#PCDATA)>
    ]>
```

**Update**

Workaround by reading the DOCTYPE from an existing file that contains the DTD an no data:

```
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->load('graph.xml');

    //get the actual root element
    $graph=$doc->documentElement; 

    $graph->appendChild($doc->createElement('id','12'));
    $graph->appendChild($doc->createElement('url','foo.png'));      

    echo $doc->saveXML();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can use [data URIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) (as suggested [here](http://hu.php.net/manual/en/domimplementation.createdocumenttype.php#103361)) to embed the content of your DTD into your document,
- or you can create an empty document, which holds the DTD nodes already, and then instead of creating documents with `DOMImplementation`, you could just parse this pre-made document as it can hold such data in its [internalSubset](http://hu.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocumenttype.php#domdocumenttype.props.internalsubset) property, f.ex.:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
  <!DOCTYPE graph [
    <!ELEMENT graph (id,url)>
    <!ELEMENT id (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT url (#PCDATA)>
  ]>
  <graph />
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. While it doesn't explain how to generate the proper DOCTYPE with createDocumentType, your suggestion of parsing an existing document pointed me to a workaround that I'll be using for now. See update to my question.

Comment: The docs says, you cannot generate the proper DOCTYPE with `createDocumentType()`. It has only the following arguments: `qualifiedName`, `publicId` and `systemId`. You cannot manipulate the `DOMDocumentType` object either (it has only read-only properties). I think you only have these two workarounds.